# Get an instance variable from Mailer in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, actionmailer

I am trying to verify that a given instance variable is set when calling a method in my UserMailer model. I am using RSpec and can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the mailer :

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def client_connexion_notification(connexion)
    @connexion = connexion
    mail to: "test@test.com", subject: "Connexion!"
  end
end
```

And the test :

```
it "should set @connexion" do
  UserMailer.client_connexion_notification("stackoverflow")
  UserMailer.instance_variable_get(:@connexion).should == "stackoverflow"
end
```

I know I should be calling instance_variable_get on an instance of the model, but I guess ActionMailer is acting different because you're not really supposed to create a new instance of it. (Method new is private)

One of the alternatives I could think of is testing the content of the actual email being created with ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, but I would rather test the actual content of the variable.

BTW, I thought I could get it with ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.instance_variable_get(:@connexion), but nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead test for the presence of the variable in the resulting email, like so:

```
it "should set @connexion" do
  mail = UserMailer.client_connexion_notification("stackoverflow")
  mail.raw_source.should include("stackoverflow")
end
```

This assumes that the mail is not multipart.

Comment: Yup I already thought of that (as I said in the content of the question), but that's not really ideal for what I want to test.

Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of your post. As you say yourself, the problem is you're not creating instances of ActionMailer.

I can not think of any good ways to test for the value of @connexion directly. Is there any reason why checking the mail output is not a good option?

Comment: Well it's just that I simplified it here, but on this project I'm working on, depending on 3 variables my mail output can have 9 different content - which will make testing more complicated.
Just testing those 3 variables would have been easier, but I guess I have no choice then. Thanks for the help!